# Prestashop - Product default combination doesn't want to save

Tags: prestashop

I'm relatively new with working with Prestashop and I cannot fix one problem.

After deleting one combination for a product new default combination doesn't want to save and therefore the price showing on the website is not correct.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the combination that you have deleted is a default combination, you can try the following steps to set another default combination.

Open table `ps_product_attribute` and filter the rows with product ID of the product you want to edit. You will see a column `default_on` in this table, just edit it to 1 for the combination you want to set as default.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced exactly the same problem (Prestashop 1.6.23) - the default product combination did not want to save.

In debug mode received an error stating the "default_on" field was already set for this product.

Solved it by opening the database table "ps_product_attribute" and searched via the product ID. Deleted the old combinations manually (which were not displayed at the back-end anymore and not in use). Then I was able to set the default combination again.

Sidenote: in our Prestashop setup (with a custom theme) the price was showing as 0 EUR (front-end) before getting the default combination to save again.